# SQL query for entries of last N jobs

Tags: sql, sqlite, max, sql-order-by

I have the following table:

```
UnixTime  JobID  Status   Data
 1010        1   start     ...
 1012        1   running   ...
 1013        2   start     ...
 1015        1   ok        ...
 1016        2   running   ...
 1017        3   begin     ...
 1018        2   error     ...
 1021        3   running   ...
 1022        4   start     ...
 1023        5   start     ...
```

etc, so basically jobs keep adding entries concurrently

I am looking for an efficient query to return all entries of the latest (by time) N jobs

So find the first (by time) entry for each job, then using that get the latest N jobs with all their entries

So for the above table and N=3 I will get:

```
 1017        3   begin     ...
 1021        3   running   ...
 1022        4   start     ...
 1023        5   start     ...
```

I understand such query will involve PARTITION BY but not sure how to proceed ?

(I need a valid SqlLite query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need this query:

```
SELECT JobID
FROM tablename
GROUP BY JobID
ORDER BY MAX(UnixTime) DESC LIMIT 3
```

that returns the last 3 distinct `JobID`s.

You can use it with the operator `IN`:

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename
WHERE JobID IN (
  SELECT JobID
  FROM tablename
  GROUP BY JobID
  ORDER BY MAX(UnixTime) DESC LIMIT 3
)
ORDER BY UnixTime;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=52313d8fb1ce4c5e6ef890bbece58a80).

Comment: I expected this to be much slower than the join in the other answer but it's not ! and overall simpler thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm . . . If the jobs are incrementing sequentially, you can use `dense_rank()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             dense_rank() over (order by jobid desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum <= 3  -- or whatever number you want
order by unixtime;
```

If you need to go by the times, you can first get the earliest time for each job and then use `dense_rank()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             dense_rank() over (order by min_unixtime desc, jobid desc) as seqnum
      from (select t.*,
                   min(unixtime) over (partition by jobid) as min_unixtime
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
where seqnum <= 3  -- or whatever number you want
order by unixtime;
```

Another fun method uses aggregation:

```
select t.*
from t join
     (select jobid, min(unixtime) as min_unixtime
      from t
      group by jobid
      order by min_unixtime desc
      limit 3
     ) t3
     on t.jobid = t3.jobid
```

Comment: Thanks, jobs are not incremented sequentially see the example table, also as for your last solution why a left join ? Wouldn't that return all entries ?

Comment: @kofifus . . . You are totally right about the last solution.  I don't know how the `left` meandered into there.